# MongoDB Backups: Expire Data from Collections by Setting TTL

Tags: mongodb, backup

I have read the MongoDB's official guide on [**Expire Data from Collections by Setting TTL**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-data-from-collections-by-setting-ttl). I have set everything up and everything is running like clockwork.

One of the reasons why I have enabled the TTL is because one of the product's requirements is to auto-delete a specific collection. Well, the TLL handles it quite well. However, I have no idea if the data expiration will also persist on the MongoDB backups. The data is also supposed to be automatically deleted from the backups. In case the backups get leaked or restored, the expired data shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @D.SM data is not deleted from backup. One solution could be to encrypt your data, e.g. with [Client-Side Field Level Encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption/)

For every day use a new encryption key for your data. When your data should expire, drop according encryption key from your password storage. With this your data becomes unusable, even if somebody restores the data from an old backup.

Answer (score 2):

Backup contains the data that was present in the database at the time of the backup.

Once a backup is made, it's just a bunch of data that sits somewhere without being touched. The documents that have been deleted since the backup was taken are still in the backup (arguably this is the point of the backup to begin with).

If you want to expire data from backups, the normal solution is to delete backups older than a certain age.